# SVG not working when access on localhost. Why?

Tags: svg, xhtml, localhost

Does anybody know why the same code from this page http://emacsformacosx.com/ would not render when hosted on a local tomcat server?

I am trying to play with some SVG but can't see to make it work locally. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page is XHTML, so it should be served with an appropriate Content-Type header. If the page is served as text/html, then Firefox and Chrome (the only two I've checked in) won't recognise the XML namespaces necessary for the SVG to work.

Although the live page is being served with the header

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

this is not, strictly speaking, correct. In my tests, serving it with

```
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8
```

causes it to render correctly, and is the appropriate type for XHTML.

Note that you'll have to detect Internet Explorer (and other browsers that don't understand XHTML) on the server and change the content type to `text/html` - if presented with the `application/xhtml+xml` content type IE will prompt the user to download the file; for `text/xml` it will show the pretty-printed XML document tree (although occasionally it will get confused and manage to display the HTML correctly through content sniffing).

EDIT: as codedread says, if you want to serve raw SVG files you'll need to use the SVG content type, but in this case the file is in fact XHTML with inline SVG in a separate namespace, so the XHTML type is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set up your server to serve the proper MIME type for SVG: image/svg+xml

More info here: http://www.planetsvg.com/tools/mime.php

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Apache Server you can instruct [which mime type](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) to use for these images, just add these two lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

Answer (score 1):

As NickFitz and codedread have mentioned, for embedded SVG to work your page needs to be served as `application/xhtml+xml`.  There are at least three ways of achieving this with Tomcat:

1. Edit your server or application [web.xml](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml) to change the default MIME type, or the [MIME type](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.MimeMapping) for a particular file extension.
2. If your page is a JSP, set the contentType in the [page directive](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/1.2/syntaxref1210.html)
3. If you want to accommodate IE users, [set the contentType dynamically](http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97329_03/web.902/a95882/jspnls.htm#1009349) based on the `HTTP_ACCEPT` header sent in the HTTP request ([I blogged this approach in the context of mobile devices](http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/2007/10/16/my_first_website_for_mobiles?blog=2)).

Alternatively, split your SVG content into a separate files, then it won't matter what content type your page is.  IE won't render the SVG, but it will at least show the rest of the page.  You can take all the SVG out of the page and the link to it, though there are still [some browser compatibility issues](http://e.metaclarity.org/52/cross-browser-svg-issues/).

Finally, if you just want to look at a static page with embedded SVG off your local hard disk with no servers involved, changing the file extension from `.html` to `.xhtml` may work.