# Browser loads image with status: 200 but shows blank image on localhost

Tags: php, http, xampp, localhost

I have a locally hosted web app, whose root directory looks like this:

```
|- index.php
|- img
   |-physics.svg
```

When I access `http://localhost/img/physics.svg`, the vector image is successfully displayed on the page. When I access `http://localhost/index.php`, which includes the line:

```
<div style="...; background-image: url(./img/physics.svg)"></div>
```

The browser shows a status 200 in the Network tab of the dev tools. However, the image loaded appears to be **a blank**. Is there any explanation/solution to this problem?

Also, this problem only happens on localhost. When I deploy the app to gcp, it works just fine, showing the images as normal.

Comment: Tried clearing your browser cache? Does the _Network_ panel show the correct mime type and size for the resource? Taking a guess here but perhaps your HTTP server is delivering `.svg` as `text/plain` or `text/xml`

Comment: Thanks! I eventually fixed it by setting the header content type to ``image/svg+xml``

Comment: In that case, throw an upvote towards [this answer in the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51988510/283366)